# Joomla 3 - How to set content of the editor field?

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor

I have a editor field which I would like to populate with HTML content:

```
<fieldset name="basic">
    <field name="Code" type="editor" label="Code" description="" width="300" filter="safehtml" default="" />
</fieldset>
```

Can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: were you able to achieve what you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the editor dynamically in the getInput() as

```
protected function getInput() {
    $editor = JFactory::getEditor();
    return $editor->display($this->name, $this->value, '550', '400', '60', '20', false); }
```

If this doesn't help you can create it using the JHtml class

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the default value, add `default` element within the field and include the content wrapped with CDATA:

```
<fieldset name="basic">
    <field name="Code" type="editor" label="Code" description="" width="300" filter="safehtml">
        <default><![CDATA[<h1>Sample Text</h1>]]></default>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi Sharky, Thanks for this. Is it possible to add an editor field through a custom field type as I will be adding the data dynamically? Thanks.